# Magento Upgrade 1.9.2.3 from 1.4.0.1: Upgrade installer thrown error: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: magento, upgrade, magento-1.4

Try to ***upgrade a magento system from 1.4.0.1 to lastest 1.9.2.3***.

Getting error to *Mage_Customer module's at upgrade installer* file `mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.0.7-1.4.0.0.8.php`

**Throwing error:**

```
a:5:{i:0;s:199:"Error in file: "app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/
customer_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.0.7-1.4.0.0.8.php" - SQLSTATE[HY000]:
General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint";i:1;s:970:"
#0 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
```

- **How to resolve this**.
- **What is reason for error**;

Comment: https://github.com/nexcess/magento

Comment: what is this naveenbos

Comment: Something related to the installer/upgrade file https://github.com/nexcess/magento/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.0.7-1.4.0.0.8.php, i saw this result when i did a googling, but i am not sure this can help you.

Comment: Could you maybe try to pinpoint what is exactly not working in that file ? if you do a ```die('ok');``` before the create table of customer/form_attribute, does it work ? If you do it right after the create table, does it work still ? Or do you get the error ?

Answer (score 3):

### The reason :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Actually means that the script failed to create a foreign key constraint, as the error actually stands it, but the reason for those to fail is actually kind of simple, mysql will not allow you to create a FK if the two fields you are trying to link don't have the exact same type and length.

Now from the line 31 of this update script you can indeed find a creation of a table with the addition of a foreign key constraint on the field `attribute_id`

```
$installer->run("
CREATE TABLE `{$installer->getTable('customer/form_attribute')}` (
  `form_code` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `attribute_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`form_code`, `attribute_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_FORM_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE` (`attribute_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMER_FORM_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `{$installer->getTable('eav_attribute')}` (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Customer attributes/forms relations';
");
```

But you can also see that the field `attribute_id` is created as a smallest but with no length.

Since this link to the table `eav_attribute` you can now try to compare the field type and a field of type `smallint` from a dummy table that you would create.

```
CREATE TABLE `dummy_table` (`attribute_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
# you should now have the table named "dummy_table"

show fields from dummy_table where field = 'attribute_id';
# the Type should be "smallint(5) unsigned" and Null should be "No", if not, that is why the foreign key creation fail.
show fields from eav_attribute where field = 'attribute_id';
# the Type should be "smallint(5) unsigned" and Null should be "No"

drop table `dummy_table`;
# clean up of our testing table
```

### The resolution :

So now, if the field `eav_attribute.attribute_id` is not `smallint(5) unsigned not null` then you can safely edit `eav_attribute.attribute_id` to make it `smallint(5) unsigned not null`.

If the field you created in your dummy table is not `smallint(5) unsigned not null` then just edit the line 34 of the file `mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.0.7-1.4.0.0.8.php` so the field is created correctly.

```
  // `attribute_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL, -- old line
  `attribute_id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, // new line, so the field have the right type
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. I will check

Comment: Change  to `attribute_id smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL`  but still getting same error

Comment: what does ```show fields from eav_attribute where field = 'attribute_id'``` shows ?

Comment: and does the table ```customer_form_attribute``` exists already on your database ?

Comment: If the table is created, then it should be something else after the create table statement that would fail, right ? Can you pinpoint what line is doing it ? Adding a simple ```die('ok')``` and moving it from php line to php line would actually tell us what instruction is actually making that fail.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that when exporting the original database you set Check Foreign Key Constraints to Off.

When importing this database the problem should not be there anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the issue of database engine. I also faced same kind of issue few months back so i *`compared my updated magento database tables engine`* with the 1.9 database table engine and observed that all tables have **MyISAM** as database engine, So I changed it as in **1.9 database and my issue got resolved**.

Comment: hi Vishal,i willcheck